# NRPE Protocol description

Tags: java, network-protocols, nagios, nrpe, jnrpe

I need to query a nrpe nagios server from a Java application remotely just as **check_nrpe** would do:

```
check_nrpe -H 192.***.***.*** -p 56** -c "check_load"
```

When I say "from a Java application" I mean I want the results to be received and processed at my Java application. The first idea I had was to call the "check_nrpe" command from my application and retrieve its output and return value but I would like more a standalone solution where no external programs are called.

I don't need to wait for state changes, just eventually check the monitor state. Since I have been unable to locate any Java library (should I try JNRPE?), I would like to implement the protocol **check_nrpe** and **nrpe** daemon use to communicate.

Have any of you tried this before? In that case, do you have a description of this protocol?

If your answers are negative I will try to analize the protocol using whireshark but any clue will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An explanation of NRPE protocol from [Andreas Marschke](http://about.me/andreas.marschke) blog, [The NRPE Protocol explained](http://andreasmarschke.wordpress.com/2013/09/24/the-nrpe-protocol-explained/) (on [gitHub](https://github.com/andreas-marschke/nagios-nrpe/blob/master/share/protocol-nrpe.md) too)

Anyway, [JNRPE](http://jnrpe.sourceforge.net/) have a full working implementation of the protocol, you can download `jcheck_nrpe-2.0.3-RC5` source code and take a look at `jcheck_nrpe-2.0.3-RC5\src\main\java\it\jnrpe\client\JNRPEClient.java` class for a sample client who's using `jnrpe-lib-1.0.1-RC5`.

`jnrpe-lib` have two concrete classes which implements the protocol request and response

- JNRPERequest.java
- JNRPEResponse.java

The full protocol implementation classes can be found at `jnrpe-lib-1.0.1-RC5\src\main\java\it\jnrpe\net\` folder

Comment: When you answered I was already chewing jcheck_nrpe code and trying to make it work. It seems it won't be a problem. Thank you

Comment: I made it work but I had to disable SSL because of version issues. Enough for me.